# avoid data redundancy on ms access using vb 2010

Tags: vb.net

I need some help with regards on how to identify if the info that i will input on my database is existing or has the same record on my database..Pls i need some help... thank you

here is my code for SAVE BUTTON

```
Private Sub btnsave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsave.Click

rs = New ADODB.Recordset
With rs
    'check if important item is null '
    If txtappln.Text = "" Or txtappfn.Text = "" Or txtappmn.Text = "" Or txtclass.Text = "" Or txtcnum.Text = "" Or txtaddr.Text = "" Or txtbrgy.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Some object in the Applicant Personal Information or Classification or Ctrl Number is not filled up", MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        .Cancel()
    Else
        'Save'
        .Open("Select * from Applicant", con, 2, 3)
        .AddNew()
        .Fields("LAST_NAME").Value = txtappln.Text
        .Fields("FIRST_NAME").Value = txtappfn.Text
        .Fields("MIDDLE_NAME").Value = txtappmn.Text
        .Fields("ADDRESS").Value = txtaddr.Text
        .Fields("CLASSIFICATION").Value = txtclass.Text
        .Fields("CONTROL_NO").Value = txtcnum.Text
        .Fields("BARANGAY").Value = txtbrgy.Text
        MsgBox("Record has been save !!", vbInformation)
        .Update()
        .Close()
    End If
End With`
```

Comment: a) you are open to SQL injection attacks; b) whatever uniquely identifies this person/thing (like maybe Control_No?) is a candidate for the PK for the table; just check if it already exists; otherwise you are kind of in a bind because text fields like those are open to dupes (Bob vs Bobby, Mike vs Michael etc).

Comment: thanks for the advice....but is there any option(like setting up a condition)  in order to avoid record duplication..  there`s another thing that i would like to confirm, that the system that currently develop is STAND ALONE DBMS.

Comment: almost anything non trivial will have an ID (like an employee ID) to short circuit dupe tests.  If it exists, that person is already present.  otherwise test if Last Name AND Address AND maybe 1-2 of those numbers already exist before adding.

Comment: can you make a sample code?